# google ajax search API for .net

Tags: api

I use this library to search web from my application:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/

I want to search this term with library above:

imdb.com/title/ "2012.2009.Bluray.1080p.DTSMA5.1.x264.dxva-FraMeSToR"

in site named:framestor-hd.org

using this code:

```
Google.API.Search.GwebSearchClient client = new Google.API.Search.GwebSearchClient("framestor-hd.org");

            string phrase =
                (@"imdb.com/title/ ""2012.2009.Bluray.1080p.DTSMA5.1.x264.dxva-FraMeSToR""");

            IList<Google.API.Search.IWebResult> results = client.Search(phrase, 10);
            foreach (Google.API.Search.IWebResult result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1} => {2}", result.Title, result.Content, result.Url);
            }
```

and no thing found.

but when [manually search term some results where found (please click link below to see result)

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=imdb.com%2ftitle%2f%20%222012.2009.Bluray.1080p.DTSMA5.1.x264.dxva-FraMeSToR%22%20site%3Aframestor-hd.org

How can I get those results in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for output. This example returns nothing, but instead prints out the search result.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i search that term and get results from my c# app?